# Konva Transformer attaches differently for different draw style for Rectangle

Tags: konvajs

I am facing an issue in which Transformer of Konva attaches to the sides of the Rectangle differently when I draw the Rectangle with different styles.  For example - When I draw Rectangle with positive height and width it attaches itself as required but when any or both of height or width gets negative it attaches itself differently to the Rectangle. I have shared a small demo below so please help me resolve the issue. Try changing the height and width of The Rectangle Positive and Negatives and check the transformer it will appear differently.

And also the cursor sign also appears wrong for case when height is positive and width is negative or vice versa when I try to resize from corner anchors.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ll0n4x3or9

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in `Konva.Transformer`.

But I recommend not to use negative values for `width` or `height` properties. Some browsers may not draw such shapes.

If you still need negative values you can use `scaleX = -1`  or `scaleY = -1` instead.